# ip routing - How to find the gateway

Tags: ip, routing

Im trying to add a route to my routing table to reach other networks. I can ping the machines on the internal network but not the ones that are in other networks.

Things i tried so far: i added a route but i couldnt ping the machines
I tried to add a route and i got an error that says: Nexthop has invalid gateway

[image: my routing table]

What should i do to reach the other networks. Thanks

my local ip:10.0.2.15
ip i want to reach: 10.86.74.7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

route add -net 10.86.74.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw <gateway for 10.0.2.0>

Might need to play with netmask if target net not /24.

You can check gateway using `arp -a` or `netstat -r`

Comment: Hello,
I added a route as you say (10.0.2.1 as gw) and now i got Destination Host Unreachable. 
What did i do wrong?

Comment: It's very difficult to say what's wrong without knowing your network. Why have you decided that 10.0.2.1 is your gateway? Was it confirmed by your IT? If you're absolutely sure that this is the gateway, then you should ask IT whether your desired 10.86.74.0 is actually reachable through that gateway, it might be not true. Organization can have multiple isolated network ranges that are only reachable through some specific junction points. If you know absolutely nothing, then you may try different gateway IP addresses to test what's happening - but again, it's waaay better to check with IT.

Comment: If route is valid (i.e. it's possible to reach the subnet from the gateway/router but target is not responding) you can use nmap to discover ports open on the target(s), like: `nmap 10.86.74.*`

Answer (score 0):

This is the steps for troubleshooting:

1. Figure out the gateway's IP address. It can be done by pinging to 10.10.2.x (x = 1,2,3,4,250,251,252,253,254, try one number per time). Your real gateway should response the ping command. If you cannot found any real gateway, may be you config the wrong subnet mask (/24).
2. If you found the real gateway, then remove the current default route, and add a new one route to the real gateway.

Comment: Hi, there is more than 1 ip that responds to ping in 10.0.2.0 network. But it didnt work when i try few that responded, maybe ive done something wrong.  Also im adding a picture to the post of the route to 10.86.74.0

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know, there is simply no other way but to try every IP address in the local subnet (10.0.2.0/24):

1. Add route like `ip route add 10.86.74.0/24 via 10.0.2.x`
2. Ping something you know exists on the network you’re trying to reach
3. If unsuccessful, remove route, go to next IP address, repeat

Pinging IP addresses on the local subnet or scanning it will not get you a list of valid routers, but could be used to narrow down the search space.

You can automate this process using a script.

You can also ask whoever is responsible for the information.

An additional router may not exist on the local subnet. There may be no route at all to the desired network. Access to the desired network could be controlled by firewalls.